# How to hide html table row based on column value?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a html table where I need to hide all the rows where column value is 39(value_type==39).

Below is my table structure:

```
<c:forEach items="${rapportkonf.conf}" var="conf" varStatus="clist">    
    <div id="tabs-${conf.value}">
    <table style="font-size: 12px;"><tr><th style="display: none;">Configuration_id</th><th style="display: none;">Types_id</th><th style="display: none;">Sort_no</th><th>Value</th><th>ValueType</th><th>Fromdate</th><th>Todate</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${conf.attl}" varStatus="status">  
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none;"> 
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].configuration_id" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td style="display: none;"> 
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].types_id" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td style="display: none;"> 
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].sort_no" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td> 
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].value" /></td>
      <td>  
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].value_type" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td>
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].fromdate" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td> 
      <form:input path="clist[${clist.index}].attl[${status.index}].todate" readonly="true"/></td>
      <td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Please tell me how to hide rows in present situation.

Comment: some code would help us help you... http://jsfiddle.net/. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You have to write query accordingly. Try using [Except](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm).

Comment: I need to filter it through jsp page.